# Retained property being deallocated

Tags: ios, memory-management, properties, retain, nszombie

I am fairly new with Objective-C memory management and although I thought I understood it, I have a problem that I cannot manage to solve.

I have this property:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate *dateDisplayed;
```

that I assign in my viewDidLoad with a custom method:

```
self.dateDisplayed = [self dbDateFormatToNsDate:@"15/11/2011"];
```

My `dbDateFormatToNsDate` method looks like this:

```
- (NSDate *) dbDateFormatToNsDate:(NSString *) date {
    NSDateFormatter *d = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [d setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];
    NSDate *toReturn = [d dateFromString:date];
    [d release];
    return toReturn;
}
```

So it returns an autoreleased object (if NSDate follows the convention). But when I get out from `viewDidLoad`in another function trying to read `dateDisplayed`:

```
[dateDisplayed isEqualToDate:[self dbDateFormatToNsDate:@"15/11/2011"]]
```

I get an NSZombie exception. Thanks for any help!

Comment: FYI, creation of NSDateFormatter is expensive. You should create one and hold on to it and re-use it for subsequent calls. You can just stick it in a `static` variable and use `dispatch_once()` to initialize it.

Comment: Ok thanks will implement that.

Comment: I actually found out what's causing it, I made a mistake in my original code. It turns out that doing self.dateDisplayed = [self dbDateFormatToNsDate] works. But dateDisplayed = [self dbDateFormatToNsDate] doesn't. I have no idea why though

Comment: It's because the former is going through the property, while the latter is skipping the property and mutating the instance variable directly (which bypasses the normal memory management imposed by the property).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When assigning using self.property the property is retained because the setter methos is called but when just assigning without using `self.` it isnt.  Assuming of course that you have `retain` in the propery definition of the .h file.

---

You could `[d autorelease];` instead.  I might be totaly off on this, but the `toReturn` NSDate might need to keep the formatter around even after youve released it, causing the bad access:

Try:

```
- (NSDate *) dbDateFormatToNsDate:(NSString *) date {
    NSDateFormatter *d = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [d setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];
    NSDate *toReturn = [d dateFromString:date];
    [d autorelease];
    return toReturn;
}
```

Comment: I actually found out what's causing it, I made a mistake in my original code. It turns out that doing self.dateDisplayed = [self dbDateFormatToNsDate] works. But dateDisplayed = [self dbDateFormatToNsDate] doesn't. Pretty weird...

Comment: Ah, yea.  When assigning using self.property the property is retained, when just assigning without using `self.` it isnt.  Assuming of course that you have `retain` in the propery definition of the .h file.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are returning an object created by a method that does not start with alloc, copy, mutableCopy, convention says you should autorelease it.

Autorelease means that it will be release in the future.  If the caller of the method needs it to stick around, then they will retain it.

Read the memory management guide:

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html

Here's the rules:

***1 & 3 apply to that method.  2 applies to a calling class that may need to hold it.***

**1 - You own any object you create**
You create an object using a method whose name begins with “alloc”, “new”, “copy”, or “mutableCopy” (for example, alloc, newObject, or mutableCopy).

**2 - You can take ownership of an object using retain**
A received object is normally guaranteed to remain valid within the method it was received in, and that method may also safely return the object to its invoker. You use retain in two situations: (1) In the implementation of an accessor method or an init method, to take ownership of an object you want to store as a property value; and (2) To prevent an object from being invalidated as a side-effect of some other operation (as explained in “Avoid Causing Deallocation of Objects You’re Using”).

**3 - When you no longer need it, you must relinquish ownership of an object you own**
You relinquish ownership of an object by sending it a release message or an autorelease message. In Cocoa terminology, relinquishing ownership of an object is therefore typically referred to as “releasing” an object.

**4 - You must not relinquish ownership of an object you do not own**
This is just corollary of the previous policy rules, stated explicitly.